# How to set alias name for field name in query population in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I trying to set alias name from reference field after query population but I don't know how to handle it, here my code to query data:

```
const postData = await postModel
    .find({ author: id })
    .populate('author')
    .sort({ updatedAt: -1 });
console.log(postData)
```

Example data inserted in database:

```
{
   "_id": "63636e95422ce851ec25d680",
   "author": {
      "_id": "6362a7313410b2941a18a559",
      "username": "apple",
      "fullname": "Apple",
      "email": "my-example-email@gmail.com",
      "createdAt": "2022-11-02T17:21:53.092Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-02T17:21:53.092Z"
   },
   "content": "hello world, i was born to say goodbye world!",
   "createdAt": "2022-11-03T07:32:37.384Z",
   "updatedAt": "2022-11-03T07:32:37.384Z"
},
```

I want to set aliasing name from `author` field to get the results like below:

```
{
   "_id": "63636e95422ce851ec25d680",
   "author": {
      "user_id": "6362a7313410b2941a18a559",
      "user_fullname": "Apple",
      "user_email": "my-example-email@gmail.com",
      "user_updated": "2022-11-02T17:21:53.092Z",
   },
   "content": "hello world, i was born to say goodbye world!",
   "createdAt": "2022-11-03T07:32:37.384Z",
   "updatedAt": "2022-11-03T07:32:37.384Z"
},
```

How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [$project](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage after $sort stage in your aggregation pipeline, [like this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XJtlEU0DAmu)